# MySQL function returns string error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have create this function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION func05(x1 int) 
RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN 
  RETURN (SELECT txt  FROM strutture INNER JOIN dizionario ON dz_nome = idtxt WHERE idls = x1 LIMIT 0,1)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But returns this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 6

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of the line starting with `return`

Comment: Btw, if the body of the function is a single sql statement, you do not need begin - end, nor changing the delimiter.